# Question about the objective function of Linear regression

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, linear-regression

Suppose we have some data and I am fitting those data with a simple linear regression model. As the graph show below, the black line represents the true model that generated the data. Denoted it as:
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \epsilon$$
where $\epsilon$ is normal distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. The red line represents the estimated model and denoted it as:
$$\hat y = \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1 x_1$$
Let the residuals denoted by $\hat\epsilon$. The objective of linear regression is to minimize the sum of the square of residuals $\sum_{i=1}^n{\hat\epsilon^2}$ so that we can find a estimated line that is close to the true model. However, intuitively, in order to find a estimated line that is as close as possible to the true line, we just need to minimize the distance between the true line and the estimated line. That is, $|\hat\epsilon - \epsilon|$(as the graph shown below). This leads to the new objective function $Min \sum(\hat\epsilon - \epsilon)^2$.


What confuse me the most is that the least square method is trying to fit a estimated model that is as close as possible to all the observations but not the real model. However, a estimated model that is close to the observations doesn't guarntee to be also close to the real model since an observation with a large error term will draw the estimated line away from the true line. For this reason, the objective function $Min \sum(\hat\epsilon - \epsilon)^2$ makes more sense to me even thought in practice, we can not take $Min \sum(\hat\epsilon - \epsilon)^2$ as our objective function since $\epsilon$ is unknown.

My question is then, why do we use Min$\sum\hat \epsilon^2$ as our objective function if it is not guranteed to generate a model that is close to the true model? Are $Min \sum\hat\epsilon^2$ and $Min \sum(\hat\epsilon - \epsilon)^2$ equivalent to each other(Or one could lead to another)?


Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.


[image]

Comment: If we knew the true line then why would we need to make any estimation in the first place?

Comment: The $\epsilon_i$ values are unknown.

Comment: @mathreadler I understand that $\epsilon$ is unknown. So in practice, we can not take $Min \sum(\hat\epsilon - \epsilon)^2$ as the objective function. But I wonder why we pick $Min \sum \epsilon^2$. Does it imply $Min \sum(\hat\epsilon - \epsilon)^2$?

Comment: A value can not *imply* a value. Implication is about logic and sets. Usually one picks to minimize the squared errors as it leads to solving a convenient linear least squares problem.

Comment: Also, the errors that are being talked about are as compared to if the data fits the parametrized model, not the errors compared to some *true function* hiding behind the sampled values. If it is possible to fit the parametrized model perfectly, then we can get a sum of squared errors = 0. But that has nothing to do with any true thing hiding behind the values that we measure.

Comment: Very nice diagram, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Comments:

(a) In some applications one minimizes $D = \sum_i |\hat e_i|$ instead of
$Q = \sum_i \hat {e_i}^2.$ An advantage of $D$ (my notation) is that it puts less
emphasis on points far from the line produced by data. (But one usually
pays due attention to points far from the usual line made using $Q;$
this is part of 'regresssion diagnostics'.)
Advantages of using $Q$ are computational simplicity and existence of
standard distributions to use in testing and making CIs.

(b) As mentioned by @littleO, expressions involving $\epsilon_i$ are off
the table because the $\epsilon_i$ are not known.

(c) As for general 'objectives' of regression, I immediately think of
two: First, *prediction* of $y$-values from new $x$-values (not used in
making the line). Second, *understanding relationships* among variables:
either to verify known theoretical relationships as holding true in practice or to 
discover new relationships.

*Note:* Recent hand surgery has reduced me to hunt-and-peck typing for a few days, and probably to making even more typos than usual. If you have rep to fix them, please feel free.

Comment: Thanks for the help :-). What confuse me the most is that the least square method is trying to fit a estimated model that is as close as possible to all the observations but not the real model. However, a estimated model that is close to the observations doesn't guarntee that it would also close to the real model since an observation with a large error term will draw the estimated line away from the true line. Then, what is the point to have $Min \sum \hat \epsilon^2$ as our objective function?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fit data is to try and fit the *Total Least Squares*. It does not only consider the error in the *function direction* but also in the *variable direction*. The shortest squared distance to the curve: ${\epsilon_x}^2+{\epsilon_y}^2$ instead of just the $y$ direction.

Here is a picture showing the total least squares distances: (by Netheril96 (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares))):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help :-). I have updated my question. Can you take a look at it again.

Comment: No sorry I can't. Don't update questions after you got answers. Especially not if it risks invalidating answers.

Comment: I just rephrased my question to make it more clear but didn't change it.